# Select words and count from long text (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, select, count

I need to get hashtags and count them from a long text. I know I can do this with regex but I couldn't. If you can help me I'll appreciate it. Here's my example text;

> #paris #love #spring #outdoor #life #istanbul #par #sacrecoeur #paris #france #latex #dog Thats what the world is, paris after all, an endless battle of contrasting memories. I can see clearly now the rain is gone. #music I can see all obstacles in my way. #paris  #queenstreet #foreveronvocationNever felt more glamorous. #ski #music #skiing #skier #terrainpark #paris #snowboard #snowboarding #snowboarder #longboard #longboarding #longboarder #skateboard #skateboarder #skateboarding #winter #just my voice and my good friend Danny Marin will dj for our auditory exploration. #stack #over #flow to be or not to be #poem #music #paris

I need to get just hashtags like "#paris" and count each hashtags, finally order the hashtags by iteration. e.g.

> #paris (6)
>    #music (3)
>    #... (2)
>    #... (2)
>    #...(1)
>    #...(1)
>    #...(1)

Comment: `$tags = array_count_values(array_filter(str_word_count(strtoower($sentence), 1, '#')),  function($value) { return $value[0] === '#'; });`

Comment: Did you try something? Show us some code. What do you mean by "I know I can do this with regex but I couldn't", why don't you want to use regex?

Comment: @Ian why was this question put on hold for beeing to broad? There is four answers on this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 preg_match_all("/(\#\w+)/", $string, $array);
$array = array_count_values($array[1]);
asort($array);

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key ($value)<br>\n";
}
```

Should give you what you need

Edit: sorry forgot the index of array

Working example:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d1fe24cbc8deedd24f7825ea4e48eaa691b8d401

Comment: @MertZaim any luck with this?

Comment: Actually I don't have a text. I make a mysql query and while loop with hundreds of posts and gather them with a variable. When I use that variable as $string in your code, I get kind of different result like this:Array ( [#kolera] => 1 [#paris] => 1 [#love] => 1 [#spring] => 1 [#outdoor] => 1 [#life] => 1 ) Array ( [#istanbul] => 1 [#par] => 1 ) Array ( [#sacrecoeur] => 1 [#paris] => 1 [#france] => 1 [#latex] => 1 [#k] => 1 ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( [#efes] => 1 [#izmir] => 1 [#2010] =... Could you tell me how to get rid of Arrays and "[]  ()" ?

Comment: for($i=0;$i<=count($array[1]);$i++){ echo $array[1][$i] . "<br>"; }

Comment: @MertZaim i will update the answer

Comment: @MertZaim Sorry I meant: foreach($array as $key => $value) {
  echo "$key $value";
}

Comment: Thanks @Andreas it's almost done. it counts words for each posts. i mean if there are 3 #paris hashtag in a photo it says "#paris 3" and after that it says also #paris 1"... this is the result what i get; `#kolera 1#paris 1#love 1#spring 1#outdoor 1#life 1
#istanbul 1#par 1
#paris 3#sacrecoeur 1#france 1#latex 1#k 1


#efes 1#izmir 1#2010 1

#louvre 1#museum 1#paris 1#france 1
#moulinrouge 1#paris 1#2016 1
#lise 1



#rome 1#2016 1


#merzifon 1#jet 1#askerlik 1
#metoday 1#morning 1#monday 1#mondaymood 1#picoftheday 1`

Comment: @MertZaim not sure what is missing but I updates the code and the working example. I added the `()` around the value and a `<br>\n` and sorted the array on value high to low. It's hard to know what you want when you don't say it.

Comment: @MertZaim was it the way you wanted?

Comment: kind of. It still gets hashtags separately. I think the reason is while loop. these are my all codes; `$query = mysql_query("select * from photos order by photo_id desc limit 5000");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){ 

$description = $row["description"];

preg_match_all("/(\#\w+)/", $description, $array);
$array=array_count_values($array[1]);
arsort($array);

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key ($value)<br>\n";
}

}` ****** output: `#outdoor (1)
#life (1)
#spring (1)
#love (1)
#paris (1)
#kolera (1)
#par (1)
#istanbul (1)
#paris (3)
#kool (1)
#latex (1)
#paris (1)`

Comment: @MertZaim And that IS EXACTLY what you write in "output" in your question. `I need to get just hashtags like "#paris" and count each hashtags, finally order the hashtags by iteration. e.g.`. I'm sorry but I did what you wanted.

Comment: Yes you did but i have a while loop and i wasn't aware that it depends on while loop or string. I did exactly what you gave me but unfortunately it doesn't help me . Anyway I really appreacite it. thank you very much for your exertion. i'll mark your answer is the best answer.

Comment: @MertZaim is your idea to grab all hastags from all pictures?

Comment: Yes and take 10 of them to show "most popular hashtags"

Comment: @MertZaim that is new information :-) ok. I think you need to move some code outside the while loop and merge arrays as you go in the while loop. First move out (and below) everything from the while loop except the preg_match. After preg_match add this line: `$totalarray = array_merge($totalarray, $array);` totalarray is now the complete list of all hastags. I think you need to add above while loop `$totalarray = "";` just to make sure the code works in the while loop. Then the code below while loop need needs a smal twek, $array should be replaced with $totalarray. Try that.

Comment: I've tried what you write and it doesn't show anything. this is the code: `$query = mysql_query("select * from photos order by photo_id desc limit 5000"); 
$totalarray = "";

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){ $description = $row["description"]; 

preg_match_all("/(\#\w+)/", $description, $array);
$totalarray = array_merge($totalarray, $array);

}

$totalarray=array_count_values( $totalarray[1]);
arsort( $totalarray);
foreach($totalarray as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key ($value)<br>\n";
}`

Comment: @MertZaim i need to sleep to get my brain to work again. But there is two things that strike me now that I see the code. `$totalarray = array_merge($totalarray, $array);` should probably be ...$array[1]);, and `$totalarray=array_count_values( $totalarray[1]);` may need to be changed to ....$totalarray);. Do you get any error messages? You can use var_dump($array); to see how the array is built (or $totalarray). That way you can see if there is something that is pointing in the wrong direction.

Comment: @MertZaim does $description update each time the loop runs? Have you checked that it does?

Comment: I finally did it! I developed your code to this; `$query = mysql_query("select * from photos order by photo_id desc limit 5000"); $totalarray = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$description = $row["description"];
preg_match_all("/(\#\w+)/", $description, $array);
$totalarray = array_merge($totalarray, array_unique($array[1]));}
$totalarray=array_count_values($totalarray);
arsort($totalarray);
$andreas = array_slice($totalarray, 0, 10, true);
foreach($andreas as $mert => $zaim){
echo "$mert ($zaim)<br>\n";
}` Thanks for your support :)

Comment: @MertZaim, I'm honored to be in your code! :-) Good that you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

split the string into an array on ' #'

split each element of that array on ' ' keeping only the first word

get the count of each token and store in a parallel array

sort using the parallel array

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php), here's an example:

```
<?php

$html = <<< EOF
#paris #love #spring #outdoor #life #istanbul #par #sacrecoeur #paris #france #latex #dog Thats what the world is, paris after all, an endless battle of contrasting memories. I can see clearly now the rain is gone. #music I can see all obstacles in my way. #paris #queenstreet #foreveronvocationNever felt more glamorous. #ski #music #skiing #skier #terrainpark #paris #snowboard #snowboarding #snowboarder #longboard #longboarding #longboarder #skateboard #skateboarder #skateboarding #winter #just my voice and my good friend Danny Marin will dj for our auditory exploration. #stack #over #flow to be or not to be #poem #music #paris
EOF;
preg_match_all('/(#.*?\S+)/im', $html, $hTags, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_r(array_count_values($hTags[1]));
```

---

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [#paris] => 5
    [#love] => 1
    [#spring] => 1
    [#outdoor] => 1
    [#life] => 1
    [#istanbul] => 1
    [#par] => 1
    [#sacrecoeur] => 1
    [#france] => 1
    [#latex] => 1
    [#dog] => 1
    [#music] => 3
    [#queenstreet] => 1
    [#foreveronvocationNever] => 1
    [#ski] => 1
    [#skiing] => 1
    [#skier] => 1
    [#terrainpark] => 1
    [#snowboard] => 1
    [#snowboarding] => 1
    [#snowboarder] => 1
    [#longboard] => 1
    [#longboarding] => 1
    [#longboarder] => 1
    [#skateboard] => 1
    [#skateboarder] => 1
    [#skateboarding] => 1
    [#winter] => 1
    [#just] => 1
    [#stack] => 1
    [#over] => 1
    [#flow] => 1
    [#poem] => 1
)
```

---

**Regex Explanation:**

```
(#.*?\S+)

Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(#.*?\S+)»
   Match the character “#” literally «#»
   Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed) «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
   Match a single character that is NOT a “whitespace character” (any Unicode separator, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed, next line) «\S+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
```

---

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/EUmsgw)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the trick using PHP if you want:

```
$tagString = "#paris #love #spring #outdoor #life #istanbul #par #sacrecoeur #paris #france #latex #dog Thats what the world is, paris after all, an endless battle of contrasting memories. I can see clearly now the rain is gone. #music I can see all obstacles in my way. #paris #queenstreet #foreveronvocationNever felt more glamorous. #ski #music #skiing #skier #terrainpark #paris #snowboard #snowboarding #snowboarder #longboard #longboarding #longboarder #skateboard #skateboarder #skateboarding #winter #just my voice and my good friend Danny Marin will dj for our auditory exploration. #stack #over #flow to be or not to be #poem #music #paris";

$countArray = array();

foreach (explode("#", trim($tagString, '#')) as $tag) {

    $tag = trim($tag);

    if (array_key_exists($tag, $countArray)) {

        $countArray[$tag] = (int) $countArray[$tag] + 1;

    } else {

        $countArray[$tag] = 1;
    }
}

arsort($countArray);

var_dump($countArray);
```

which give:

```
array(34) {
  ["paris"]=>
  int(5)
  ["music"]=>
  int(2)
  ["skateboard"]=>
  int(1)
  ["snowboarding"]=>
  int(1)
  ["snowboarder"]=>
  int(1)
  ["longboard"]=>
  int(1)
  ["longboarding"]=>
  int(1)
  ["longboarder"]=>
  int(1)
  ["skateboarder"]=>
  int(1)
  ["terrainpark"]=>
  int(1)
  ["skateboarding"]=>
  int(1)
  ["winter"]=>
  int(1)
  ["just my voice and my good friend Danny Marin will dj for our auditory exploration."]=>
  int(1)
  ["stack"]=>
  int(1)
  ["over"]=>
  int(1)
  ["flow to be or not to be"]=>
  int(1)
  ["snowboard"]=>
  int(1)
  ["skier"]=>
  int(1)
  ["love"]=>
  int(1)
  ["skiing"]=>
  int(1)
  ["ski"]=>
  int(1)
  ["foreveronvocationNever felt more glamorous."]=>
  int(1)
  ["queenstreet"]=>
  int(1)
  ["music I can see all obstacles in my way."]=>
  int(1)
  ["dog Thats what the world is, paris after all, an endless battle of contrasting memories. I can see clearly now the rain is gone."]=>
  int(1)
  ["latex"]=>
  int(1)
  ["france"]=>
  int(1)
  ["sacrecoeur"]=>
  int(1)
  ["par"]=>
  int(1)
  ["istanbul"]=>
  int(1)
  ["life"]=>
  int(1)
  ["outdoor"]=>
  int(1)
  ["spring"]=>
  int(1)
  ["poem"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

You can test online here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3058b887590845e33685b25e14e21df9959e94e7

Comment: You know there is 5 #paris? and your code does not make any difference if there is a # or not

Comment: @Andreas it is because the of the spaces around the tags. Add `$tag = trim($tag)` in the loop. I will fix the answer when I get home in 30 mins.